# Looking for help in resolving this c error

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, networking

I run an online game, which runs on a server built in c++ and c (to my understanding).
Recently, I opened a ticket on their github page, because I was receiving an error like this:
** Waiting for network I/o, bad file descriptor.

their response, and fair enough, was that it is not a bug with them, but is a limit on my server that is being hit.
they suggested looking at ulimit and sysctl.
Sysctl seems quite advanced, and I am still research that before I go poking around in things I do not understand, however, ulimit seems to indicate there is no file i/o or file descriptor limits, and all outputs I try, both scanning users, and scanning in general with ulimit simply says unlimited.

In that regard, does anyone know a specific place I should be looking to resolve this error, or specific calls to, say opening files, that I should be looking at for not closing correctly, or some such?
The github topic was: https://github.com/lisdude/toaststunt/issues/15

I have also attached a code snippet from the server where this occurs:

```
int
mplex_wait(unsigned timeout)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    int n;

    tv.tv_sec = timeout / 1000000;
    tv.tv_usec = timeout % 1000000;

    n = select(max_descriptor + 1, &input, &output, 0, &tv);

    if (n < 0) {
    if (errno != EINTR)
        log_perror("Waiting for network I/O");
    return 1;
    } else
    return (n == 0);
}
```

I hope this helps. C is not my strong suit, so let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. For instance, how is struct timeval defined?

Comment: @machine_1 A [mre] is a good thing, but defining `timeval` is a bit overkill. Don't you think?

Comment: @klutt At least, the OP must show the name(s) of the header files he is using.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with this function. If you are getting "bad file descriptor" then the program is trying to pass invalid file descriptors to `select`, which is a bug in the program (no matter what the developers of the program say). Perhaps the bug might be *triggered* by running out of file descriptors (I don't know whether it is or not, but the developers think it is). `select` does not return "bad file descriptor" just because the program runs out of file descriptors.

Comment: `input` and/or `output` are not set up correctly. Cannot say more without seeing the code.